# XMLHttpRequest funciona en Firefox pero Chrome, no

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo una función para cargar síncrona y asíncronamente información de una base de datos que esta graba y recupera mediante una petición por XMLHttpRequest y que hasta hace dos meses funcionaba pero, ha actualizado Chrome su navegador y me ha fastidiado.

Esta es la función:

```
function sendRequest(url,data,type) {
if (typeof(data) == 'undefined') {
    data = null;
}
    
if (typeof(type) == 'undefined') {
    type = (data === null ? 'GET':'POST');
}
    
var async = false,
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (req) {
    req.open(type, url, async);
    if (type=='POST') {
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; Charset=utf-8;');
    }
    req.send(data);
}
return req;
}
```

En Firefox funciona perféctamente pero en Chrome, no. Aparece en ambos navegadores el siguiente mensaje en consola: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience".

Si en la función req.open() quito el async, que lo necesito en false, ya no aparece la advertencia.

Cuál es la forma adecuada de corregirlo?

Comment: Literalmente el mensaje significa: *XMLHttpRequest síncrono en el hilo principal está en desuso debido a sus efectos perjudiciales para la experiencia del usuario final*, como bien dice @Trauma, ¿hay algún motivo que justifique el uso de una petición síncrona?

Comment: No hay una necesidad imperiosa de utilizar síncrona, pero la aplicación fue diseñada así hace 1 década y es ahora cuando no puede usarse. Mala experiencia no hay independientemente de lo que diga el mensaje. Esto se puede migrar a asíncrona?

Comment: No hay mala experiencia, pero puede haberla tarde o temprano. El problema es que en las peticiones síncronas el hilo principal queda bloqueado mientras se procesa la petición y basta un pequeño cambio en el contexto para que empiece a haber problemas (por ejemplo, crecimiento del número de usuarios), hoy día casi todas las peticiones son asíncronas y por eso Chrome te manda ese mensaje. [Revisa la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) allí hay ejemplos que te ayudarán a modernizar el código.

Comment: La solucion es mas sencilla de lo que crees, simplemente pon todo el codigo que tenga que ver con una peticion `AJAX` dentro de una funcion. asi te debera funcionar. y si amigo mio, eso que tienes ahi es `AJAX` pero realizado con javascript puro. en pocas palabras si necesitas ejecutar esa peticion una funcion debe encargarse de ello, no puede estar en el contexto global.

Comment: Sí, sí, se que es ajax jeje pero esto está escrito en JS puro jeje. Es que data esto de...2005 o por ahí ahora que lo pienso. Miraré ambas soluciones y probaré. Gracias.

Comment: @Qadesh sobre todo trata de que la `XMLHttpRequest` y todo lo que tenga que ver con ello quede en una funcion, ya que justo creo que ese es el problema.

Comment: @Riven eso va a ser difícil, hay un montón como esa pero creo que todas las funciones, o al menos desde donde se llaman, recurren a esta. A ver si logro dejarlo bien que no soy muy fan de las peticiones asíncronas jeje

Comment: @Qadesh posiblemente dificil, pero es necesario, dejarlo en un scope global se considera deprecated en este caso. y hara que las peticiones no funcionen.

Comment: Habrá como 50 llamadas en toda la aplicación, ya que es un lms, y convertirlo a asíncrono, hace que ni guarde ni recupere los datos ya que no 'espera' a que los contenidos estén cargados.

Comment: @Qadesh Ajax es de naturaleza asincrona, y no se recomienda cambiar ese comportamiento a sincrono porque pueden ocurrir errores inesperados, de todas maneras las promises hacen mas facil el manejar el codigo asincrono para que no te ocurra ese problema de que no se 'espera a que los contenidos esten cargados', sin embargo es 100% necesario acomodar todo eso que tienes afuera en funciones por separado, y que cada una se encargue de alguna peticion en especifico.

Comment: O aun mejor, crear una funcion que se encargue especificamente de que puedas realizar una peticion asincrona con la informacion que te plazca y que te devuelva el valor que te plazca en una promise (ya que al ser ajax asincrono toca asi).

Comment: Bueno, veré que puedo hacer, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a proponerte una solucion generica que te ayudara para que no tengas que crear multiples funciones que te hagan una peticion ajax, en vez de ello se usaria esa misma funcion para todo, voy a ponerte este pequeño ejemplo:

```js
function ajax(method = "GET", url, body){

    return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
        const xmlh = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const data = new FormData();

        if(body){
            for(let prop in body){
                if(prop === "data"){
                    for(let bodyProp in body[prop]){
                        data.append(bodyProp, body[prop][bodyProp]);
                    }
                }else if(prop === "headers"){
                    for(let headerP in body[prop]){
                        xmlh.setRequestHeader(headerP, body[prop][headerP]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        xmlh.open(method, url);
        xmlh.onload  = e => res(e.response);
        xmlh.onerror = e => rej(e);

        if(method.toUpperCase() === "GET"){
            xmlh.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlh.send();
        }else{
            xmlh.send(data);
        }
        
    });

}

//Ejemplo de uso:
ajax("GET", "http://google.com", 
    {
        data: {
            name: "your name",
            gender: "male",
            age: 18,
            children: false
        }
    }
).then(res =>{
     //aqui atrapas la respuesta de ajax (res).
}).catch(e =>{
     //Aqui atrapas el posible error que te devuelva ajax.
});
```

De esa manera tienes una funcion reutilizable configurable con los datos que necesites para que puedas usarla, realmente entrar en detalles es un poco complicado en este caso.

Pero en resumen, la `Promise` te ayuda a manejar el codigo asincrono de mejor forma, `FormData` es un builder que permite enviar un conjunto de datos haciendo uso de una estructura parecida a un `JSON`.

Los ciclos usados se usan para configurar tanto en la peticion (`xmlh`) los `headers` adicionales que quieras enviar (si necesitas esto), y tambien a su vez se configura la data a enviar por el `FormData` si se usa una peticion `POST`, ya que en este caso el `FormData` es solo usado para la peticion tipo `POST`.

Tambien comprobamos como debemos enviar la peticion, en caso de que sea `GET` o `POST`.

**Posdata**: la verdad no he comprobado este codigo (no lo he ejecutado), simplemente se me ocurrio, pero si este codigo no te llega a funcionar dejame la observacion yo lo corrijo cuando tenga un poco mas de tiempo.

Comment: Agradezco y entiendo las funcionalidades que propones. Tengo que ver dónde cargar algo similar ya que la parte donde va no permite, o mejor dicho no ejecuta, código escrito en jQuery como $.ajax o jQuery.ajax. La versión de jQuery que usa la plataforma es 1.7.1 que, no puedo actualizarla pero veré si puedo meter noConflict. Está complejo, la verdad.